# strange results between local development and staging

Tags: php, arrays, object, laravel

I am running a fairly simple script that should return a set of results from the database, the results are then parsed into a backbone collection.

Locally an object of objects gets returned, i.e

```
{
  {},
  {},
  {},
}
```

where as on the staging server, an array of objects gets returned - this is correct, so I get a response that looks like like this,

```
[
    {},
    {},
    {},
]
```

The 2 instances are running the same the code, and PHP versions and the same installations of laravel, why would my local machine return an object and my remote machine return an object?

All I doing is running,

```
$projects = array_unique(array_merge($owned_by_me, $managed_by_me, $sold_by_me, $owned_by_my_organisation, $client_projects, $collab_projects), SORT_REGULAR);
return Response::json($projects, 200);
```

I have never seen anything like this before.

Comment: If something is different with output then something is different. Enviroment or configuration files.

Comment: Can you check what type the output of `array_unique` is? It should be an array...

Comment: @lukasgeiter it looks like locally `array_unique` is returning an object, and on staging `array_unique` is returning array....is there a way to stop `array_unique` returning an object?

Comment: @Udders you checked the valued returned by `array_unique` using `print_r` or `var_dump`? It always returns `array`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that since `array_unique` leaves indexes like they are, it can't be converted into an array. Say you pass in this array:

`array('foo', 'foo', 'bar')`

You will get:

`array('foo', 'bar')`

Which is actually:

`array(0 => 'foo', 2 => 'bar')`

So because of the gap in the index count it will be converted into a JSON object.

Use `array_values` to "reorder" the indexes:

```
$projects = array_unique(array_merge($owned_by_me, $managed_by_me, $sold_by_me, $owned_by_my_organisation, $client_projects, $collab_projects), SORT_REGULAR);
$projects = array_values($projects);
return Response::json($projects, 200);
```

Also, the difference between your environments seems to be the data you're dealing with

Answer (score 0):

`array_unique()` always return `array`. Most probably there is something in the Laravel configurations. I don't know how `Response::json()` works but if it uses the `json_encode()` native PHP function then it can be told to return objects instead of arrays by adding the flag `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` to its second parameter. Maybe you can find this in the configuration files.